# UIPickerVIew Selection Indicator lines not working properly

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview, simulator

So I finally have my `UIPIckers` working and populated, and they look all good in the **storyboard** and assistant editor, however when they run in the **simulator** (iPhone 6s) there is only one selection indicator line, at the bottom of each selection, and this is appearing regardless of whether or not **show selection indicators** is ticked or unticked. (this is new to swift 2.0)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is there any solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mind if you set "show selection indicators" or not. From iOS 7, you can't hide these lines. I bet you are experiencing that on simulator, and taht's just an issue of your screen resolution, not displaying such thin lines. It should be fine on your real device.